# Dúvida (Hibernate) - JSF

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Estou fazendo um cadastro de funcionário, e nesse cadastro possui já departamentos cadastrados no banco. Então, nesse momento percorro o banco para apresentar os dados na view, mas quando finalizo o cadastro, esse "departamento" selecionado anteriormente, ao invés de só cadastrar ele como o id do departamento, ele está criando um novo departamento e salva na tabela funcionário o novo id.
Método para recuperar os departamentos:

```
    public List getProjetos() {

        ProjetoDAO projetoDAO = new ProjetoDAO();
        List<Projeto> listaProjeto = projetoDAO.listarProjeto();

        return listaProjeto;
    }
```

Outro problema que estou tendo é que estou fazendo o lazy no momento que chama o get do "departamento", sei que o problema é aqui, porque sempre que ele dá o get, vai criar um novo.

```
    public Projeto getProjeto() {

        if (projeto == null) {

        projeto = new Projeto();

        }

        return projeto;

        }
    }
```

Classe Funcionário

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "tbl_funcionario_has_tbl_projeto", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_funcionario_fun_codigo") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_projeto_pro_codigo") })
private List<Projeto> projeto;
```

A dúvida é como fazer para que ele verifica que já existe esse departamento e não criar um novo?

Comment: Você anotou o relacionamento nas entidades?

Poste as entidades. 

A tabela no banco é uma só (funcionario departamento) ou separada?

Comment: Elá é separada... postei aí o relacionamento...

Comment: Sua dúvida se baseia em criar um método novo ou você suspeita que suas anotações estão erradas?

Comment: Minha dúvida é como fazer para quando chamar o get do Projeto, ele não criar outro projeto e sim recuperar o id e salvar na tabela do funcionário.

Answer (score 0):

Esta difícil compreender. 
Sugiro separar em dois post, um para cada problema.
E postar todas as entidades relacionadas.

De qualquer forma deixe eu tentar o de funcionários.

Me parece um relacionamento @OneToOne de Funcionário para Departamento.
algo assim:

```
@Entity
public class Funcionario{
   @Id
   private Integer funcionario;
   private String nome;
   @OneToOne
   private Departamento departamento
   // get and sets
}

@Entity
public class Departamento{
   @Id
   private Integer departamento;
   private String nome;
   // get and sets

}
```

Lembrando que o Objeto departamento persistido deve ser atribuído a funcionário.

Comment: Marcelo, problema é na hora de cadastrar um novo funcionário, quando seleciono o projeto que quero que o funcionário seja cadastrado, ao invés de só salvar o projeto com o id dele, ele está criando um novo projeto, com as mesmas informações.

Comment: É que isso pode ser um problema no mapeamento da entidade ou no DAO. 
Veja como esta a sobrescrita do método equals de sua entidade.
O que pode estar acontecendo? Ao persistir ( merge ou persist ) a JPA não esta reconhecendo o objeto já persistido. 

Veja se o Objeto em questão esta sendo gerenciado pelo entity manager. (http://www.arquiteturacomputacional.eti.br/2013/02/entenda-o-ciclo-de-vida-das-entidades.html).

Se nada resolver. Só vendo o código completo.

Comment: Entendi, vou dá uma olhada nessa documentação que me passou, obrigado.